# Get results from wordpress data custom table

Tags: database, wpdb, select

Firstly i created a custom table into the wpdb :

```
  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'countdown_table';

  $sql = '
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `styleName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `css` blob NOT NULL,
  `expiration` blob NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ';

  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
  dbDelta( $sql );
```

Then i created a form to send values into the custom table :

```
<p>Style Name</p>   

<form action="" method="POST">

<input type="text" name="style_name">
<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>

if (isset($_POST['style_name'])) {

$style_name = $_POST['style_name'];

 global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->insert( 
        'countdown_table', 
        array( 
            'styleName' => $style_name 
        ), 
        array( 

            '%s' 
        ) 
    );

}
```

And here is the problem to get results from the table :

```
 global $wpdb;

    $output = '';

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'countdown_table';

    $name = 'styleName';

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$table_name ) );

    if ( $results ) {
       foreach ( $results as $result ){
       echo $result[0];
    }
```

The problem is that i cannot display the saved data or do i did something wrong in the code for table creation or inserting data

Comment: Check your [Database setup](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3933/guide-how-to-add-database-details-to-your-question) as by now it's pretty much guessing. Please update your question then. Thanks. Also please add some context to your code. It's unclear where and when this code executes which could be a problem of its own.

Comment: Seems really unlikely you should need a custom table for this. Especially one using blobs.

Comment: Since you have set all field to `NOT NULL` wont you have to add the other fields in your insert query?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you issue is with the below code piece:

```
if ( $results ) {
    foreach ( $results as $result ){
       echo $result[0];
    }
}
```

`echo $result[0];` should just be `echo $result;`.

`$results` is your array so to use `$results[0]` (note the s) you would need a for loop and not a foreach loop.

```
if ( $results ) {

    $arrLen = count($results);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $arrLen; $i++ ){
       echo $result[$i];
    }
}
```

is what you want if you want to use $results[n] targeting.